# Can't access MAUI project settings on Visual Studio Version 17.6.0 Preview 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, maui

This is my Visual Studio information:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.6.0 Preview 6.0
VisualStudio.17.Preview/17.6.0-pre.6.0+33626.354
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA489
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.6.323.41838
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.6.323.41838
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.6.323.41838
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.6.0-3.23212.2+d78a163b525fd73efb768f4f0095590f9ade3469
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.4.21 (main@8f226a8)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.6.41 (790a401)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

Node.js Tools   1.5.50201.1 Commit Hash:0a76e2b03608f2fdee0e7d2e38e83d7721149b5f
Adds support for developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   6.6.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.6.0.2317807+3be43f6abbdc8d585f17c168f03b18420aab1062
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SonarLint for Visual Studio   6.15.0.67199
SonarLint is an extension to your favorite IDE that provides on-the-fly feedback to developers on new bugs and quality issues injected into their code.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.6.6.2
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQLite & SQL Server Compact Toolbox   4.8
SQLite & SQL Server Compact Toolbox adds scripting, import, export, rename, query execution and much more to SQL Server Compact & SQLite Data Connections.

StylerPackage Extension   1.0
StylerPackage Visual Stuido Extension Detailed Info

Syncfusion .NET MAUI Template Studio   21.1.35
Provides project templates for creating an .NET MAUI Application using Syncfusion Maui components.

Syncfusion ASP.NET Core Project Templates   21.1.35
Provides project templates for creating an ASP.NET Core Web Application using Syncfusion ASP.NET Core components.

Syncfusion Blazor Code Generator   21.1.35
Insert Syncfusion components code snippet in the existing razor file of Blazor application

Syncfusion Blazor Template Studio   21.1.35
Provides project templates for creating an Blazor Application using Syncfusion Blazor components.

Syncfusion EJ2 Web Conversion and Migration   21.1.35
Converts and migrates a web project into a Syncfusion web project.

SyncfusionMenu Extension   21.1.35
SyncfusionMenu Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Syntax Visualizer   1.0
An extension for visualizing Roslyn SyntaxTrees.

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20329.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

UnoPlatformPackage Extension   1.0
UnoPlatformPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Visual Basic Tools   4.6.0-3.23212.2+d78a163b525fd73efb768f4f0095590f9ade3469
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.6.0-beta.23174.5+0207bea1afae48d9351ac26fb51afc8260de0a97
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Unity   17.6.1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Unity

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

VSPackage Extension   1.0
VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Xamarin   17.6.0.251 (d17-6@318364c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.6.6.0 (remotes/origin/d17-6@cb430751d1)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.6.32 (98c12a2)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.0.6 (d17-5/a200af1)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: 6dd9def
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-5@149d70fe
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.1@68c69d8
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-5@9f02d77


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.4.0.6 (97731c92c)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

I know preview versions are way more unstable, however, is there a workaround to this? I had to upgrade because I need some fixes that are only available on .NET MAUI 8.0.100-preview.3.23178.7.

However now whenever I try to access the properties of a MAUI application I get this erro

```
System.ArgumentException: Expected 8 values for property AndroidRule::AndroidPackageFormat, but got 2.
Parameter name: values
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property.Update(ImmutableArray`1 values)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property..ctor(PropertyMetadata metadata, ImmutableArray`1 values, PropertyContext context, ImmutableHashSet`1 varyByDimensions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.PropertyContextFactoryBase.ToProperty(IUIPropertySnapshot property, Page page, Category category, Int32 order, PropertyContext propertyContext, IPropertyEditorRegistry propertyEditorRegistry)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<HandleDataAsync>g__CreateProperties|14_5(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<HandleDataAsync>g__ProcessInitialData|14_1(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<InitializeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<CreateAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertiesEditor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.AsyncLoadContent.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Initialize>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

[image: Properties Error]

Is there a way to fix this without going back to the stable version?

Comment: Try deleting solution's hidden .vs folder

Comment: Hi @adamasan, you can report this problem in the Visual studio directly. Please see this document about [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I've just reported the problem using the channel you've recommended.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've tried this. But the problem occurs even with new projects.

Comment: @adamasan, did you figure out a workaround? I'm stuck on this exact problem.

Comment: @eengstroem Sorry for the huge delay, but never. I've dropped MAUI for a while until it's somewhat usable, so I don't even know if now it works.